# How do I disable minification for pre-optimized-min items in my theme?

Tags: sxa, sxa-cli

### Sitecore/SXA 10.2

I find it very difficult to know exactly which part of my code is broken when the theme scripts are mangled beyond my comprehension. What can I do to improve this experience?

Take for example this piece of code:

**Minified**

[image: Minified]

**Original**

[image: Original]

**Note:** I'm using a CDN which handles the minify process in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be other options available, but the easiest I found begins in the *config.js* included with the SXA theme. Making the configuration changes below will result in a *pre-optimized-min* file bundled with the variable/function names intact.

Here is the original **minifyOptions** provided:

```
minifyOptions: {
    js: {
        compress: {
            hoist_funs: true,
            passes: 1
        },
        toplevel: false
    },
    css: { compatibility: 'ie8' }
}
```

Here is the updated **minifyOptions**:

```
minifyOptions: {
    js: {
        compress: false,
        mangle: false,
        toplevel: false
    },
    css: { }
}
```

**Note:** SXA makes use of the npm-uglify-es and npm-clean-css packages.

Comment: This worked for me on 10.2, thanks!