# How to disable minification for JS CSS files in SXA

Tags: sxa, gulp

I would like to have the pre-optimized-min.js without minification to be able to troubleshoot issues.

So, I followed the answer here - [How do I disable minification for pre-optimized-min items in my theme?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/32946/how-do-i-disable-minification-for-pre-optimized-min-items-in-my-theme)

and changed the `minifyOptions` as suggested. [But that did not work, and hence this question]

Next, executed the command `sxa build Js` in the Shared Theme folder. That did not work. The generated pre-optimized-min.js file is still minified.

Using Sitecore 10.1.3

Comment: Try to delete existing pre-optimized-min.js and then recreate it?

Comment: @GauravAgarwal Yes, I always do that to ensure that it is a new file.